# std::wstring pointer assignment C++

Tags: c++, pointers, wstring

I am trying to assign a value to a wstring pointer and the value does not get assigned; however, when I break the creation and assignment of the pointer into two lines, it works. Why is this?

For example:

```
std::wstring* myString = &(L"my basic sentence" + some_wstring_var + L"\r\n");
```

The above does not work, but the below does work:

```
std::wstring temp = (L"my basic sentence" + some_wstring_var + L"\r\n");
std::wstring* myString = &temp;
```

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish. When what `myString` points to goes out of scope, it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example you are getting the address of a temporary. After that line has executed that `wstring` object you assigned `myString` to isn't available anymore (these are so called `rvalue`s by the way). I think it should be obvious that in the second example you have a real object (a `lvalue` which is valid as long as it doesnt run ot of scope.

To overcome this limitation with the scope you can directly create a `wstring` on the heap, this might better suite your situation but without further information this is hard to tell:

```
std::wstring* myString = new std::wstring(L"my basic sentence" + some_wstring_var + L"\r\n");
```

The newly created `wstring` will me initialized with the contents of the temporary rvalue.
Just do not forget to destroy the pointer after you are done with it.

With C++11 things have complicated so temporaries can be reused more often for performance reasons. But this topic is very though and will exceed this question. I just wanted to mention it because it might interesst you aswell. For a really great explanation take a look at this SO question: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

Comment: FYI C++0x is dead and is called C++11.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::wstring* myString = &(L"my basic sentence" + some_wstring_var + L"\r\n");
```

It points to a temporary object that its life time ends at the semicolon, so dereferencing the pointer and using it is *undefined behavior*.

```
std::wstring temp = (L"my basic sentence" + some_wstring_var + L"\r\n");
std::wstring* myString = &temp;
```

It points to a temporary object, but the life time is longer and dereferecing it is valid while that temporary object exists.

Comment: Your answer is great, but I accepted the above answer because Paranaix gave a similar answer and also pointed me towards more research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot assign the adress (that's what the & is) of a string constant to a variable. Have you thought about it? Where will the pointer point to?

Comment: Have you thought about your answer? What's wrong with assigning the address of a string literal to a pointer variable? The pointer will point to whatever memory location the string literal resides at.

Comment: @Praetorian: and where will that be after the temporary thing disapears?

Comment: A probably (but not neccessary!) invalid memory location, but still a memory location.

Comment: You haven't said anything about any temporary thing. I quote "*you cannot assign the adress ... of a string constant to a variable*"